# ElectronJS - How to pop up in the background

Tags: popup, electron

I’m completely new to Electron JS and I’ve tried reading through the documentation, but no to avail.

I was just wondering if there was a way to create a browser window, then show the window in behind of all the running applications. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `win.focus()` (documentation [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#winfocus)) on other windows to put them on top, letting the new one behind.

Edit:

- If by *all runnings applications* you mean even applications that are not part of your Electron app, I would suggest to use [nwm](http://mixu.net/nwm/). Assuming that you are using X11.